# DNS Server Not Responding?

Tags: server, dns, microsoft-edge

**In Microsoft-Edge**

Details 
The DNS name does not exist.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

[microsoft-edge error described by pitcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9xAG.png)

**Windows network diagnosis**
[DNS Server Not Responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylsUr.png)

**Some Description**

My Network links used to work well for a long time, now I don't know why suddenly there is something wrong.

Some strange things is :

When I use the campus network connecting through data cable, there are no such
problem.
But when I use WiFi to connect Unicom network, these problems happened.
However, I also can use part software such as Wechat and I can use Google explorer by VPN (Web page plug-in)("Because I am Chinese, I must use VPN to visit foreign website")

My computer System is Win10(64)，Can you give me some ideas to solve the problem? Thank you in advances...  By the way, I had this problem before, but it was solved automatically after a few days, I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

It is amazing! The DNS Server Not Responding question is solved when I restart the computer, but I don't know why?  I should restart computer every time when I meet with the problem? What else method can I do to solve it?